# How to display date and time from datetime column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, time

I have a staff_registered column which includes both the date and the time of when staff registered. However I want to be able to retrieve the date and the time for all the staff who registered on 22-JAN-07 how can I show the time?

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'DD MON YY 
HH:MI:SS') 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TO_CHAR (REGISTRATION_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') = '22-JAN-07';
```

I've wrote this as a starting point, I know it's wrong as it's getting today's date not 22-JAN-07 or the time but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: What if your date is 1907? Better use `TO_CHAR (REGISTRATION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '22-01-2007'` or `TO_CHAR (REGISTRATION_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'nls_date_language = american') = '22-JAN-2007'` or even better `TRUNC(REGISTRATION_DATE) = DATE '2007-01-22'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are just dealing with a typo/brain fart. You are selecting today's (SYSDATE) date in your select statement. You want to be selecting REGISTRATION_DATE. It won't matter what you search for because currently it will always return the current date until you change it to below.

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TO_CHAR (REGISTRATION_DATE,'DD MON YY HH:MI:SS') 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TO_CHAR (REGISTRATION_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY') = '22-JAN-07';
```

Unless I misunderstood your question...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not endorsing the way he chose to format his dates by any means lol, just pointing out he is dealing with a typo which was his concern.

Answer (score 1):

*Use `TRUNC` without `TO_CHAR` conversion with this filter condition :*

```
WHERE TRUNC(REGISTRATION_DATE) = date'2018-09-05'
```

*Since `REGISTRATION_DATE` is already a `DATE` type field, isn't it ?*

Answer (score 0):

if I understood right you have a column that has a string that contains what you are looking for '05-SEP-2018'

If so I would suggest something like

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'DD MON YY HH:MI:SS') 
FROM STUDENT
WHERE CONTAINS(TO_CHAR(REGISTRATION_DATE, '05-SEP-2018'))
```

Let me know if it helps